# Conditional Statement Hacks - IE8 and none IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, conditional-statements

Is anyone able to assist me before I smash my head on the wall?

I am trying to get this form to work:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="login_form">
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<input type="text" id="emailcust" name="username" class="custbox" value="Email Address" />
<input type="text" id="passcust" name="password" class="custbox" value="Password" />

<p>NON INTERNET EXPLORER!</p>
<!--<[endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]>
<input type="text" id="emailcust2" name="username" class="custbox" value="" />
<input type="password" id="passcust2" name="password" class="custbox" value="" /> 

                    <p>INTERNET EXPLORER!</p>

<![endif]-->
```

I OFFICIALLY HATE IE!

Modern browsers appear to be picking up the first IF section and ignoring the latter (as per my want), but IE8 is ignoring both IF sections.

**SOLUTION**

It seems that the entire form has to be included for each if statement. Therefore within  the following works:

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
    <div id="whatever">
    <form action="" method="post" name="login_form">
<input type="text" id="emailcust" name="username" class="custbox" value="Email Address" />
<input type="text" id="passcust" name="password" class="custbox" value="Password" />

<p>NON INTERNET EXPLORER!</p>

<input type="submit" class="cust_submit" value="Login" />
</form> 
</div>

<!--<[endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]>
    <div id="whatever">
    <form action="" method="post" name="login_form">
<input type="text" id="emailcust2" name="username" class="custbox" value="" />
<input type="password" id="passcust2" name="password" class="custbox" value="" /> 

                    <p>INTERNET EXPLORER!</p>
<input type="submit" class="cust_submit" value="Login" />
</form>
</div>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Did you really test with IE8 or with IE11 in IE8 rendering mode?

Comment: Does this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7WZ4/show/) work as you want it to work?

Comment: Tested this with IE8. But managed to find the solution (see edit above). Turns out, that the entire form needs to be included per if statement, so I suppose the break up of the form prevented it from functioning correctly.

Comment: The solution Danny needs to work for all major browsers..unfortunately I haven't tested all browsers yet :/ But now the solution works for IE8 and Chrome...fingers crossed, same principle will work for all.